# Spring STS MVC Project - Unable to Get Rid of Error

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have the newest STS build and have installed on Window 8.1. Following tutorials, I get a pom.xml error. Following any and all suggestions, including re-installing the STS does not fix it.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is  a maven configuration problem, try :

Right click on the project > run > maven build ...> goal : `eclipse:clean`

and then update the project

if the error is not fixed , then may be you have some corrupted dependencies

delete the folder `.m2` under `C:\Users\<the current user>\.m2` and update the project again, maven will load the missing jars again.

Comment: Thanks. It doing this finally showed that it was the sunfire plugin. Removed and updated. Now works!